# Replace part of the page with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a script and I want to change the language. I managed to do this using the .ajax() function in jQuery and fetching the new HTML. 
Afterwards I want to replace the old HTML with the new HTML.

However, I do not want to exchange the whole HTML, but only part of it. 
I know that the HTML returned includes a `<div id="myDivId">...</div>`, so I only want to get the content of that div from the HTML returned, and replace the content of my current div with the new content.
But, I can't seem to figure out how to fetch only that content from my new HTML. How can I do that? I tried using find, but no success.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: "action=languagepack&subAction=box&newIso="+newIso+"&country="+country,
    success: function(htmlCode){
        var box = $(htmlCode).find('#myDivId').html();

        alert(box);
    }
});
```

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [**jQuery.load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> This method is the simplest way to
>   fetch data from the server. It is
>   roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data,
>   success) except that it is a method
>   rather than global function and it has
>   an implicit callback function. When a
>   successful response is detected (i.e.
>   when textStatus is "success" or
>   "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML
>   contents of the matched element to the
>   returned data. This means that most
>   uses of the method can be quite
>   simple:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html');
```

**Loading Page Fragments**

> The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a
>   portion of the remote document to be
>   inserted. This is achieved with a
>   special syntax for the url parameter.
>   If one or more space characters are
>   included in the string, the portion of
>   the string following the first space
>   is assumed to be a jQuery selector
>   that determines the content to be
>   loaded.
>
> We could modify the example above to use only part of the document that
>   is fetched:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Comment: I did manage to do it with .load function and adding a container to the source page. Thanks. However, a new question popped up.. I updated my question with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you need HTML from only one container - then `load` is recommended way certainly. If you need some additional custom processing - are you sure that #myDivId **inside** blocks given from server and not one of these blocks? In the 2nd case you need `filter` inside of `find` (or wrap all HTML into some div to be sure that all elements will be inside it and won't be top level elements).

Answer (score 0):

Shoot that through a php, run a explode change the contents, recreate the div, replace it where you want.

You can do all this with ajax too, but trigger the php file

Answer (score 0):

try this with returned html:

```
var d = $("<div/>");
$(d).html(msg.d);
var box = $(d).find("#testDiv").html();
alert(box);
```

Comment: I get: 
Error: XML filter is applied to non-XML value ({0:({}), 1:({}), 2:({}), 3:({}), 4:({}), 5:({}), 6:({}), 7:({}), 8:({}), 9:({}), 10:({}), 11:({}), 12:({}), 13:({}), 14:({}), 15:({}), length:16})
Source File: http://192.168.44.128/project/1.0/trunk/js/core.js
Line: 127